# Recognizing Space character in C++ Program

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
char ch;
cout<<"Enter a character:";
cin>>ch;
if(ch==32)
cout<<"space";
else if(ch>=65 && ch<=90)
cout<<"upper case letter";
else if(ch>=97 && ch<=122)
cout<<"lower case letter";
else
cout<<"special character entered";
getch();
}
```

I need to check whether character entered is lower or upper case letter,special character, digit or space character. 32 is code for space but as I am entering space as ' ' on the console, its not recognizing ' ' as space.

Comment: Try printing the value of the character entered.

Comment: [`isspace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/)

Comment: Why are you using numbers instead of characters? Why not just `if (ch == ' ')`, `if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')`, etc?

Comment: Remove `#include <conio.h>` (which is a DOS remnant from 3-Decades ago). Instead just use `getchar()` to hold the terminal window open. 100% portable and doesn't immediately telegraph "I'm really not sure what I'm doing, but this was in the tutorial I'm trying to follow....". And you should really wrap it in conditionals to it is only used on windows to hold the terminal open. E.g. `#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)` then `getchar()` followed by `#endif`.

Comment: `void main` is wrong; `main` must return `int`.

Comment: @Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩᛗ  sir i also have tried to compare variable ch with ' '(space),not recognizing it as space.

Comment: @melpomene sir i have tried ch==' ' too

Comment: @meowgoesthedog i don't know how to use isspace

Comment: @melpomene i have tried int main() instead of void main() ,not returning anything on the console

Answer (score 3):

Spaces are ignored by default, use `noskipws`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char ch;
cout<<"Enter a character:";
cin>>noskipws>>ch;
if(ch==32)
cout<<"space";
else if(ch>=65 && ch<=90)
cout<<"upper case letter";
else if(ch>=97 && ch<=122)
cout<<"lower case letter";
else
cout<<"special character entered";
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Also, if you're adding `''` to the space then keep in mind that only the first character is being recognized.

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` -- you sure, with the `'.h'`? (that must be a 30 year old compiler...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP used that too. Presumably they're using Turbo C++.

Comment: I just decided to answer the question specifically, assuming their program is running fine. Not sure if it was relevant to talk about `iostream.h`, `void main` and the others.

Comment: @David C. Rankin i am using Turbo C++. i have tried to remove '.h' too

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes i am using Turbo C++. i have tried to remove '.h' too

Comment: @Samuel program is running fine but not recognizing ' ' as space

Comment: Have you added `noskipws` as I showed in the answer?

Comment: @Samuel yes i did..showing error Undefined symbol 'noskipws'

Comment: @Samuel Can you remove `<conio.h>` and use `getchar()` and replace `void main()` with `int main()`?

Comment: @Samuel Ok you did it.

Comment: @ L. F. i had used <conio.h> just for clrscr() , used getchar() it is asking for prototype, i have followed everybody answering here. problem not solved. unable to open file <iostream>,used int main() not returning anything, 'using namespace std' is showing declaration syntax error and 'noskipws' is an undefined symbol.

Comment: @AyushiSharma ["Turbo C++ is an long obsolete piece of MS-DOS software from 1994 that *predates* the first version (1998) of the language we call C++ today. Turbo C++ can’t compile C++ programs, and Turbo C++ programs cannot be compiled with C++ compilers."](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-better-compiler-Turbo-C++-or-Dev-C++) In other words, you need a **conforming C++ compiler** to compile a standard C++ program; turbo C++ is not one of them. How do you think we are supposed to help you with C++, if you do not even have a standard-conforming C++ compiler beforehand? ;-)

Comment: @L.F. what should i use instead of Turbo C++, actually the problem is after  a very long time i am working on C++, earlier i used Turbo C++, what is the current piece, tell me please

Comment: @L.F. cin.get(ch) has solved my problem in my own code, thanks alot, now its showing space, just tell me the name of current piece, i will uninstall Turbo C++

Comment: @AyushiSharma You can take a look at gcc or clang or visual C++. They are googleable :)

Comment: @L.F. what about Dev-C++?Howzz this?

Comment: @AyushiSharma It is obsolete and strongly not recommended, though not so obsolete and strongly not recommended as Turbo C++. And it isn't a compiler anyway; it internally invokes an extremely old version of gcc.

Comment: @AyushiSharma Consult [the same link](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-better-compiler-Turbo-C++-or-Dev-C++). Also see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/36896/).

Answer (score 1):

### *The* problem

`cin >> ch` discards whitespaces (including space, `\t`, `\n`, etc.) The correct way is to use `get(ch)`:

```
cin.get(ch);
```

(`noskipws` is another option mentioned in @Samuel's answer, but `get` may be easier here for a single character.)

### Other problems

1. Use `<iostream>` instead of `<iostream.h>`. `<iostream.h>` is not standard C++.
2. Use `<cstdio>`* instead of `<conio.h>`. `<conio.h>` is not standard C++.
3. Use `int main()` instead of `void main()`. `void main()` is not standard C++.
4. Use indentation instead of left-justifying. Left-justifying is less readable.
5. Use `ch == ' '` instead of `ch == 32`. `ch == 32` is not portable.
6. Use `isupper(ch)` instead of `ch >= 65 && ch <= 90`. `ch >= 65 && ch <= 90` is not portable.
7. Use `islower(ch)` instead of `ch >= 97 && ch <= 122`. `ch >= 97 && ch <= 122` is not portable.

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    std::cout << "Enter a character:";
    std::cin.get(ch);
    if (ch == ' ')
        std::cout << "space";
    else if (std::isupper(ch))
        std::cout << "upper case letter";
    else if (std::islower(ch))
        std::cout << "lower case letter";
    else
        std::cout << "special character entered";
    // std::cin >> ch; // only if you really demand it
}
```

<sub>* Even `<cstdio>` shouldn't be used in this case. If you do want to hold the window open, use `getchar()` or `std::cin >> ch` instead of `getch()`. The better way is to invoke it in a console.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Use characters themselves instead of their codes.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter a character:";
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == ' ')
        cout << "space";
    else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        cout << "upper case letter";
    else if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        cout << "lower case letter";
    else
        cout << "special character entered";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have used characters earlier before writing ASCII codes